# MVC5 Uncaught ReferenceError: addNewRowTract is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This project is part of a popup modal, I am having issues connecting function addNewRowTract(btnID, texboxID) to my `<button.... onclick="addNewRowTract('#addTract','#TractId')">`.  I included my jQuery on the same .cshtml view page @section scripts {... and element onclick is not connecting to the js.  Any direction would be super helpful.

Here's the function:

```
function addNewRowTract(btnID, texboxID) {

    var myurl = $(btnID).data('url');
    var id = $(texboxID).val();
    var taskID = $(btnID).attr('data-taskID');
    var mydata = {
        'Id': id,
        'TaskID': taskID
    };

    var tableID = $(btnID).data('table');

    $.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        data: mydata,
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $(tableID).find('tbody:first').prepend(result);
        }
    });

}

//here's the button

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" id="addTract" data-url='@Url.Action("NewTaskTract", "Tasks")' data-taskID='@Model.TaskID' data-table="#taskTractTable" onclick="addNewRowTract('#addTract','#TractId')" />
```

Comment: As i am seeing from your script, it seems that you define your script before the button, is this correct?

Comment: @AmroMustafa my apologies, no I have the button 1st then I have the section script (after all the cshtml).

Comment: I added answer, take a look and let me know.

Comment: @AmroMustafa yes your answer did take care of error Thanks!; but looks like I have some other things going on, i'm trying to use typeAhead and populate some data on the modal popup.

Comment: Could you please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to add event listener for any kind of object like the below code

> HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" id="addTract" data-url='@Url.Action("NewTaskTract", "Tasks")' data-taskID='@Model.TaskID' data-table="#taskTractTable" data-textboxid="#TractId">
```

> Javascript

```
    $('body').on('click','#addTract',function(){
      var btnId=$(this).attr('id');
      //and your rest of code
    });
```